# How to show images in UITableViewCell From NSMutableArray?

Tags: uitableview, uiimage, nsmutablearray, arrays

I'm doing this :

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 

reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[self.articlesArray 

objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"images"]];

  //  [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[self.articlesArray 

objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"images"]]];


}

return cell;

}
```

I'm doing this:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[self.articlesArray 

objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"images"]];
```

But nothing is showing in my `UITableViewCell`.

And I want to show image in left of `tableViewCell` on left side ,

Please tell me how can I do this.

Comment: Please verify that `self.articlesArray` is initialized, that every entry consists a dictionary with the key "images", that the key "images" points to an NSString and that the image exists in the main bundle (since your'e using `imageNamed:`).

Comment: yes self.articlesArray is initialized and every entry consists a dict with the key 'images' that is point to an NSString like this "http://www.dem......p-content/uploads/2011/05/learn_t.jpg"

Comment: The URL you posted is incomplete. Try to set the return value of `[UIImage imageNamed:]` to a variable and verify by debugging that it's not nil.

Answer (score 1):

I've done it by myself.

here is the solution, and it works perfectly.

```
NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: 

[[self.articlesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"images"]]];

UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

cell.imageView.image =image;
```